# How to create one variable from multiple variables in PHP?

Tags: php

Lets say we have variables: $page and $id. For example, $id=2. I wanna create new variable from existing variables $page and $id: $page2. how to do it? is it possible??

Comment: Programmatically defining variables is a bad deal in most circumstances

Comment: it'S hard to know what is being asked here. please improve your question. I hope my answer is correct

Comment: I suspect you should be using an array here rather than creating variable names at runtime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use curly brackets notation to create your variable name :
http://codepad.org/L6B5vYdG

```
 <?php        
       $number = 2;        
       ${'page' . $number} = 20 ;        
       var_dump($page2);        
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$page = 2;
${"page".$page} = "5555"; //we'll create variable from page + variable $page (2)
//$page2 has been created
$id = intval($page2); //$id will be 5555
```

Comment: What are you talking about?))

Comment: The real question is, what are YOU talking about?

Comment: I think he wants to build variable, that what my code does...

Comment: @Tural what'S wrong on my answer? I think it's correct

Comment: I meant Tural with my question, not you genesis. Sorry

Comment: @genesis: I think he was talking to Tural.

Comment: @Tomalak: aaah! Sorry cularis :) Someone downvoted and I thought it was cularis ;)

Comment: To be honest this answer _could_ use some explanation and proper quotes around strings...

Comment: yup, sorry, forgot about that. Edited

Comment: `$id` will be `"5555"`, not `5555`.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's int, not a string. why "5555" and not 5555 ?

Comment: @genesis: You assigned `"5555"` to the variable. How is that an `int`?

Comment: ooh. sorry! I'm blind and tired

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$page = 'x';
$id   = 2;

${$page . $id} = 'lol'; // variable is named `$x2`
```

Or, simpler (I can't quite tell from your question):

```
$id   = 2;

${'page' . $id} = 'lol'; // variable is named `$page2`
```

However, this is almost always a bad idea. Prefer arrays and/or objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply concatenate them, or use the a string formatter such as [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
<?php

$page2 = $page . $id
# or
$page2 = snprintf("%s-%d", $page, $id);
```